# Trump and Trumpery

Tags: etymology, differences

Reading ["Trumpery - A Twitter meme caused lookups to spike"](http://www.merriam-webster.com/trend-watch/trumpery-2016-03-03) on M-W got me wondering about Trump and Trumpery. I meant about the words itself and not about candidate Donald Trump's qualities.

[Trump](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/trump)

> a dependable and exemplary person

[Trumpery](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/trumpery)

> worthless nonsense

**How did they develop such opposing meanings?**

Comment: [Etymonline's entry for *trump*](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=trump&allowed_in_frame=0) just about covers it. The difference between sense 1 and sense 2 (which is the sense the entry for *trumpery* defers to) on that page corresponds to the difference you noticed between *trump* and *trumpery*. And explanation / history is given for both *exemplary* (i.e. *trump*) and *deceitful* (i.e. *trumpery*). The ultimate origins are murky, but interestingly both trace back to the instrument (and the onomatopoeia for the instrument).

Comment: Just a guess: trumpery from French tromper  -  to deceive?

Comment: @DanBron Add to that, the fact that in Britain, *trump* has, since the sixteenth-century, been a euphemism for breaking wind, and the poor (sic) man does carry an unfortunate surname for a possible presidential candidate.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Merriam-Webster pages that you link to actually give the etymologies of the two words (though I don't blame you for missing it; the Merriam-Webster page structure is a bit hard to follow).

According to those pages, *trump* is an

> alteration of <sup>1</sup>*triumph*

whereas

> *Trumpery* derives from the Middle English *trompery* and ultimately from the Middle French *tromper*, meaning "to deceive." […]

so they're actually unrelated, and the similarity of appearance is coincidental.